# Need regex for all HTML <input /> tags which lack a specific attribute

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match all self-closing `<input />` tags which lacks a **type** attribute.

For example, I want to find these:

```
<input size="1" />
<input name="test" />
```

But not this:

```
<input type="radio" />
```

Please note, this should be adaptable for any single attribute. I am just using type here as an example.

FYI, I am performing a search across 1000s of .html files using AstroGrep.

You can assume that the attribute is well-formed, with equals sign and double quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input(?:\s+(?!type=)\w+="[^"]*")*\s*/>
```

That should work if AstroGrep's regex flavor isn't too exotic.  I can't find an online reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is AstroGrep, but if it has negative look-ahead, you could just do

```
(?!\<input(?:[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+="[^"]*")*(?:[[:space:]]+type="[^"]*"))<input(?:[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+="[^"]*")*[[:space:]]*/>
```

Without it, it is much more laborious.